# Azure Blob Storage - What exactly does "Write Operations" mean?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) for estimating storage costs for files (more specifically, SQL backups).

I'm currently selecting `Block Blob Storage` with `Blob Storage` account type.

There's a section in the pricing calculator that shows the cost of `Write Operations` and describes which API calls are Write Ops:

`The following API calls are considered Write Operations: PutBlob, PutBlock, PutBlockList, AppendBlock, SnapshotBlob, CopyBlob and SetBlobTier (when it moves a Blob from Hot to Cool, Cool to Archive or Hot to Archive).`

I looked at the docs for [PutBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) and [PutBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block), but both don't really seem to mention "file" at all anywhere (except for PubBlob which mentions a filename).

The `PutBlob` description says:

`The Put Blob operation creates a new block, page, or append blob, or updates the content of an existing block blob.`

The `PutBlock` description says:

`The Put Block operation creates a new block to be committed as part of a blob.`

Is it 1 block per file or is a file multiple blocks?

Are those 2 Put commands used for uploading files?

Does a write operation effectively mean 1 operation per 1 file?
For example, if i have 100 files is that 100 write operations?
Or can 1 write operation write multiple files in a single op?

[image: Write Operations]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to explain it with a couple of scenarios. Considering you are using block blobs, I will explain using them only.

1. **Uploading a 1 MB File**: Assuming you have a 1 MB local file that you wish to save as block blob. Considering the file size is relatively small, you can upload this file in blob storage using `Put Blob` operation. Since you're calling this operation only once, you will be performing one write operation.
2. **Uploading a 1 GB File**: Now let's assume that you have a 1 GB local file that you wish to save as block blob. Considering the file size is big, you decide to logically split the file in 1 MB chunks (i.e. you logically split your 1 GB local file in 1024 chunks). BTW, these chunks are also known as blocks. Now you upload each of these blocks using `Put Block` operation and then finally stitch  these blocks together using `Put Block List` operation to create your blob. Since you're calling 1024 put block operations (one for each block) and then 1 put block list operation, you will be performing 1025 write operations (1024 + 1).

Now to answer your specific questions:

> Is it 1 block per file or is a file multiple blocks?

It depends on whether you used `Put Blob` operation or `Put Block` operation to upload the file. In scenario 1 above, it is just 1 block per file (or blob) because you used put blob operation however in scenario 2, it is 1024 blocks per file (or blob) because you used put block operation.

> Are those 2 Put commands used for uploading files?

Yes. Again depending on the file size you may decide to use either put blob or put block/put block list operation to upload files. Maximum size of a file that can be uploaded by a put blob operation is 100 MB. What that means is that if the file size is greater than 100 MB, then you must use put block/put block list operation to upload a file. However if the file size is less than 100 MB, then you can use either put blob or put block/put block list operation.

> Does a write operation effectively mean 1 operation per 1 file? For
>   example, if i have 100 files is that 100 write operations?

At the minimum, yes. If each of the 100 files is uploaded using put blob operation, then it would amount to 100 write operations.

> Or can 1 write operation write multiple files in a single op?

No, that's not possible.

Comment: Does this splitting of a file > 100 MB have to be done by the user prior to using Put Block, or does Put Block split it for you?

Comment: It has to be done by the user as the user decides the block size (which could be anywhere from 1byte to 100MB).

Comment: Any docs or blogs with example syntax on how to split up a file for `Put Block` uploading? I didn't see anything obvious (to me) on the Put Block docs page.

Comment: I've discovered and heard from someone that `AzCopy` module abstracts and handles the splitting of files to blocks for the user, so that the user doesn't have to think about that. So that might work as a solution for my use case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs

Answer (score 2):

Operations are at the REST level. So, for a given blob being written, you may see more than one operation for a given blob, especially if its total size exceeds the maximum payload of a single Put Block/Page operation (either 4MB or 100MB for a block, 4MB for a page).

For a block blob, there's a follow-on Put Block List call, after all of the Put Block calls, resulting in yet another metered operation.

There are similar considerations for Append blobs.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on the answer I provided. The reason I thought it was a single operation was due to an application I wrote that consumed Event Grid events. I subscribed to the event for write operations, and only ever received one event via the webhook I configured.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE September 2023**:

While @Gaurav Mantri still is totally valid, the maximum size per `Put Blob` is ~4GB and may be updated in the future again. Best get the latest values from [Microsoft docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs).

| Service version | Maximum block size (via Put Block) | Maximum blob size (via Put Block List) | Maximum blob size via single write operation (via Put Blob) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Version 2019-12-12 and later | 4000 MiB | Approximately 190.7 TiB (4000 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 5000 MiB |
| Version 2016-05-31 through version 2019-07-07 | 100 MiB | Approximately 4.75 TiB (100 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 256 MiB |
| Versions prior to 2016-05-31 | 4 MiB | Approximately 195 GiB (4 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 64 MiB |